# Django: Simplest way to create a 2-page site?

Tags: python, django

I have a site made in PHP that i need to create a django site of. I've stripped out the PHP code temporary (not much code anyways), but i'm having problems understanding how django works and how to create a simple template to display a page.

I know there's thousands of books and guides out there, but most of them go too deep or doesn't do what i need. I just need two simple pages, page1 and page2, which will be accessed through domain.com/page1 and domain.com/page2.

What is the simplest way to achieve that?

This is what i have in my urls.py file so far, is that correct at least?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.page1', name='home'),
    url(r'^$page2', 'mysite.views.page2', name='page2'),
)
```

It obviously doesn't work now cause the views aren't created.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
// qwerty

Comment: Have you considered using a more lightweight framework for such a tiny site? Flask for example

Comment: This question is far too broad (your first comment to Eva611 also gives this impression). To answer, we would essentially have to rewrite the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to walk through [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), you will find out everything Django beginner should know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.yourapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.page1', name='home'),
    url(r'^page2/$', 'mysite.views.page2', name='page2'),
)
```

The r'^page1/$ bit is python regex

in your views.py file define your views:

```
def page1:
 #something
```

This should help you get started http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I forgot to say that i want page1 to show by default, i don't want to have to go to /page1 to get there. But what do i do after this? How do i create the views?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found the most straight-forward way is:

1) **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('test.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main/test.html')),
]
```

2) **templates/test.html**

```
Hello world!
```

Classic 3-steps:

1) **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('test.html', views.test, name='test'),]
```

2) **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

3) **templates/test.html**

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: p.s. direct_to_template  method seem not to exist in Django 2

Comment: Thanks! I used Django fluently many years ago and just needed this refresher on the basics.

Comment: @krubo I am glad that it helps someone. You will catch up fast, core mechanics haven't changed much seens 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Thats more or less what I use:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'news.views.page1'),
    (r'^page2/$', 'news.views.page2'),

)
```

just for your understanding: the beginning of a line is expressed as ^, the end as $. So ^$ stands for an empty line. more about regexp: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older django than [direct_to_template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) generic view is what you need.

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^page1/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'page1.html'}),
    (r'^page2/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'page2.html'}),
)
```

Or for newer django 1.3 you need to use [class based generic views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^page1/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="page1.html")),
    (r'^page2/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="page2.html")),
)
```

P.S. Don't forget to create `page1.html` and `page2.html` template files.

Comment: I have the html files located in a folder called html which is placed in the project folder. Don't i need to write anything in views.py for it to work? Can't get it to work.